# Javascript Uncaught Typeerror - is not a consructor

Tags: javascript, constructor, typeerror

Im currently coding a project in the mvc-pattern. But i get an odd Error Message i can´t resolve. Note that my Editor(Atom, even with added Linter) doesn´t complain about my code. And i can´t find something similar on the web right now, because most of the time its just simple order mistakes, but i don´t think i made those here. Im using chrome to test my code.

```js
/* eslint-env browser */
/* global request */
var Countdown = (function() {
  "use strict";
  var that = {},
  countdownController,
  countdownView;

  function onStartGamePressed(){
    countdownView.hideMenu();
  }

  function init() {
    // Die Initalisierung der Anwendung beginnt hier
    /* Die Anfrage an die Wiktionary-API können Sie nach diesem Muster gestalten
     * Die Methode request findet sich im globalen Scope und wird durch Einbindung
     * der Datei request.js bereitgestellt.
     */
     initCountdownController();
     initCountdownView();

    request({
      success: onWiktionaryResponseAvailable,
      error: null,
      url: "https://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?action=query&origin=*&format=json&titles=student",
    });
  }

  function initCountdownController(){
     countdownController = (new Countdown.CountdownController({
      //startGame: document.querySelector(".button start-game")
    })).init();
    countdownController.setOnStartGamePressedListener(onStartGamePressed);
  }

  function initCountdownView(){
    countdownView = (new Countdown.CountdownView({})).init();
  }

  function onWiktionaryResponseAvailable(result) {
    var obj;
    console.log(result);
    obj = JSON.parse(result);
    console.log(obj);
  }

  that.init = init;
  return that;
}());
```

I get the errors on both sequences with (new Countdown....)
thanks in advance !

```js
/* global Countdown */

Countdown.CountdownView = function(){
  "use strict";
  var that = {};

    function init(){
      return that;
    }

    function hideMenu(){
      document.getElementById("menu-screen").className = "hidden";
    }

    that.init = init;
    that.hideMenu = hideMenu;
    return that;
};
```

to add the example of the reffering CountdownView.js

Comment: You have `new Countdown.CountdownController` in your code, but nothing in your code creates a property called `CountdownController` on `Countdown`, which means `Countdown.CountdownController` results in the value `undefined`. `new undefined` fails with the given error. You need to provide a constructor function and assign it to `Countdown.CountdownController` if you want `new Countdown.CountdownController` to do something useful. Voting to close as typo/non-repro/not-useful-to-others-in-future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not define any constructor for Countdown.CountdownController and Countdown.CountdownView, so the line `new Countdown.CountdownView()` and `Countdown.CountdownController()` will throw your error.

Edit:

You need to export/import your definitions in CountdownView.js and CountdownController.js.

Also I would change the definition of `Countdown.CountdownView = ...` by `CountdownView = ...` and replace the lines where you instantiate it from `new Countdown.CountdownView(...)` by `new CountdownView(...)`

Comment: I declare that in a seperate file were i wrote:
Countdown.CountdownController = function(options){…..}

    I have declared /* global Countdown

Comment: @stoesselleon well you should post that code also. People cannot help if you don't post all the relevant code.

Comment: added it now, i forgot to add that in the first place.